# assign users to group modx

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

How can i assign newly created user to the particular group in modx **Programmaticaly** ? Below is my code

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)){
  $oUser = $modx->newObject('modUser');
  $oUser->set('username', "test");
  //$oUser->set('password', "test");

  $oProfile = $modx->newObject('modUserProfile');
  $oProfile->set('fullname', $_POST['fname']);
  $oProfile->set('email', $_POST['email']);
  $oUser->addOne($oProfile);
  if($oUser->save()===false){
    echo "Error";
  }else
    echo "Done";
}
```

I googled but all i find is graphical tutorial how to create groups and edit user and then assign roles, If you know any tutorial then also its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I have been doing it, this is a posthook snippet that fires after a user registers [and the user is created]

```
<?php
$specialty = $hook->getValue('specialty');
$country =  strtolower($hook->getValue('excountry'));
$username = $hook->getValue('username');
$staff = $hook->getValue('staff-or-resident'); //Staff | Resident

$joingroup = '';
$joinrole = '';
$blockuser = 'false';

switch ($specialty){

    case 'Other' :
        $joingroup = 15; // Other 
        $joinrole = 1; //member
        $blockuser = 'true';
        break;

    // there are about 15 different groups and roles here... 

    default :
        $joingroup = '0'; // none
        $joinrole = '0'; // none 
        break;  
}

if($joingroup > 0 && $joinrole > 0){
    $user = $modx->getObject('modUser', array('username'=>$username));
    $internalkey = $user->get('id');
    $profile = $user->getOne('Profile',array('internalKey'=>$internalkey));

    $user->joinGroup($joingroup, $joinrole);

    if($blockuser == 'true'){ //block user if they belong to the "other" group
        $profile->set('blocked',1);
    }

    if(!$user->save()){
        return false;
    };
}

return true;
```

The key is the: $user->joinGroup($joingroup, $joinrole); where joingroup is the group id ~ or name and the joinrole is the role id ~ or name. It's documented here: http://api.modx.com/revolution/2.1/_model_modx_moduser.class.html#%5CmodUser::joinGroup()

Comment: So its joinGroup() :) thanks Sean, Sometimes i feel like modx documentation needs descriptive documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to create/edit something in revo >2.2 this is use "Class-based Processors" - https://www.markhamstra.com/modx-blog/2012/2/getting-started-with-class-based-processors-2.2/ to add user to group use this processor https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/develop/core/model/modx/processors/security/user/update.class.php with this - 
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+runProcessor

```
$param = array(
    'id' => 1, // user id
    'groups' => array(
        array(
            "usergroup" => 1,
            "name" => "Administrator",
            "member" => 1,
            "role" => 2,
            "rolename" => "Super User",
            "primary_group" => true,
            "rank" => 0,
            "menu" => null
        ),
        array( .... )
    )
);

$response = $modx->runProcessor('security/user/update',$param );
if ($response->isError()) {
    return $response->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Vasis i must keep your code in my special file, I must have to pay attention to your example for advanced modx development. Much appreciated.

Comment: Vasis, I tried your method too, Found that this method seems to be useful when you are logged in as admin, What if we want to normal create like using registration form ??

Comment: The processor will be executed if the user has the right to `$permission = 'save_user';`

Comment: Humnn i noticed that. I am collecting as much as documentation about modx as there is less documentation available. :)